# How to check if one of the load balancers is prone to path traversal?

Tags: python, urllib2, load-balancing, python-requests, directory-traversal

I was doing a penetration test to a website and tried to find any path traversal issues.

I founded what may be a vulnerable parameter to path traversal and succeeded to download 2 files using '**../../**' . I've downloaded these 2 files almost at the same time.  1 after 1. Time lag between the two downloads was about ~10 seconds or less.

Then I tried to fetch another file and didn't get any response and from that moment on I didn't get any response when trying to download any file (even the first 2 files that I was able to download 2-3 minutes before).

It has ModSecurity on and several load balancers too and my thought was that I just hit an unconfigured load balancer when succeeded to download those 2 files.

To mention that I tried to bypass load balancers in some ways, include trying to download the files directly from the IP. without any success.

So I was thinking of building a simple python script that will try to fetch a valid file from the specific seems-to-be vulnerable parameter using urllib python library:

```
import urllib2
import time
import os
res = open('result', 'w')
res.close()

for i in range(0, 1000000):
    if os.stat("result").st_size == 0:
        file = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/download.php?download_file=../index.php')
        output = open('result', 'wb')
        output.write(file.read())
        #time.sleep(10)
        output.close()
        i +=1
    else:
        break
```

As I'm new to python, I know this code isn't the best solution and will take huge amount of time till (if at all) it fetchs the file.

How can I improve my code so it will be done in less time for each connection (for example: to kill the connection after 3 seconds if not getting a response) and doing it using multiple threads as well? (1o or so).

Thanks